# Clone of 'git@******/common-ui-layout.git' into submodule path 'common-ui-layout' failed

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

Looking help on Jenkins, i have written jenkinsfile where in one stage i am running `sh git submodule update --init --recursive` command my job is getting failed with Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password) error. but i can see on log common-ui-layout directory is present with full access, as per my analysis i found that while hitting the submodule command its not getting authenticated or its not finding the common-ui-layout folder. Im posting my jenkinsfile here, Please provide the fix of this issue.

```
    pipeline {
  agent { 
    label 'agent.com' 
        }
  stages {stage("submodule clone"){
            steps
                {
            checkout(
            [
            $class: 'GitSCM', 
            branches: [
            [
            name: 'master'
            ]
            ], 
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
            extensions: [
                [
                $class: 'SubmoduleOption', 
                disableSubmodules: false, 
                parentCredentials: true, 
                recursiveSubmodules: true, 
                reference: '', 
                trackingSubmodules: false
                ]
            ], 
            submoduleCfg: [], 
            userRemoteConfigs: [
            [
            credentialsId: '<***ID****>', 
            url: 'https://*****gitlab.com/****/common-ui-layout.git'
            ]
            ]
        ]
        )
        }
        }

        stage("fetch data"){
            steps {
            git branch: 'patch-1',
                credentialsId: '<***ID****>',
                url: 'https://****.gitlab.com/*****/****.git'
                sh "pwd"
                sh "ls -lat"
                }
            }

        stage ("Installing pre-req"){
            steps{
            sh '''
            yarn install;
            yarn global add @angular/cli 
            '''
            }
        }
        stage('Build app') {
            steps {
            sh "yarn install";
            sh "pwd";
            sh 'git submodule update --init --recursive';
            //sh "git submodule update --recursive –remote";
            sh "yarn run ng build";
            println "BUILD NUMBER = $BUILD_NUMBER"
            println "Build Success.."
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Please refer the error snipt here [image]

Answer (score 0):

The above error got fixed after adding the rsa key. after that i got another error when i hit the `git submodule update --init --recursive` command in pipeline and return the with below error-

> Cloning into 'common-ui-layout'...
>   fatal: could not read Username for 'https://xxx.xxx.com': No such device or address
>   please refer the snippet here[image]
>   Please suggest me where i am missing?